# How to use DAX to calculate a measure based on 2 fact tables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an OnHand inventory table and a Costs Table with more rows than the ones on the OnHand inventory table (we might have costed the items, but we have never purchased them).

I have an Items dimension linking both queries.

I want to calculate(OnHand[Qty] * Costs[StandardCost]).

How can I do that? I have read that the way to do this is by creating a Bridge Table. I was wondering if there is a way to use DAX to link the OnHand query to the Items Dimension and then link it to the Costs query.

The Model is in Spanish, so I made a diagram to exemplify it
[image]

Comment: Can you paste a snapshot of your data model?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you don't need any bridge tables here. Just make sure that Dim Items is connected to both fact tables with the standard 1:many relations.

Then create 3 measures (change names as you see fit)

```
Item Quantity = SUM(factOnHand[Quantity])

Item Standard Cost = SUM(factCosts[Standard Cost])

Inventory Standard Cost =
SUMX(
    dimItem,
    [Item Quantity] * [Item Standard Cost]
)
```

The way it works:
first, we create 2 basic measures that compute quantity and costs.
Then, we iterate table 'Items' record by record. For each item, we calculate item costs, and then sum up the results.

Comment: It worked! I needed to show in the visual 2 fields from the Warehouse Dimension. I think that I had to retrieve them by using Calculate(MIN(WarehouseName), CROSSFILTER() but it became cumbersome. I ended merging the Costs and OnHand queries. Thanks!